# Retriving strings from fields with a value relation widget in QGIS

Tags: python, attributes, widget, relation, qgis

I have a few experience in python so please forgive me if my question is trivial.
I am writing a python script to export data from a Qgis vector layer. I am accessing attributes with a code like this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    a_function_to_write_in_a_file(str(f['some_field_name']))
    a_function_to_write_in_a_file(str(f['some_other_field_name']))
```

some fields are integers with a “value relation” widget: how can I retrieve the corresponding string instead of the key? Should I write a function to retrieve them from the corresponding table or is there any built-in method?